# weird series notation ANS: Generalized Hypergeometric Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, notation, hypergeometric-function, transcendental-functions

Hi I came across this curious notation on a twitter account (@infseriesbot) that supposedly posts series functions. The notation is very strange to me, hopefully some one who is familiar with this notation can guide me in understanding it. It looks something like this :

[image: series_with_weird_notation]

The notation is so weird that I don't know how to query this style in a search engine to learn about it. It seems like its encompassing some kind of series, but I don't know what this style name is to learn about it.

EDIT: ANS -> thanks to @JonathanZ supports MonicaC and @IraGessel for their swift response, these notations are for hypergeometric functions which can under special circumstances specialize into other famous functions, as seen in the comments below :D

Comment: When I see $F_1$ I think of the "hypergeometric function", which is also famous for special-casing into other better-know functions, but that notation looks just as weird to me too.

Comment: This notation is for the "generalized hypergeometric function," described, for example, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function.

Comment: ahh i see ! thanks for the response .. now I'll have to read up on this hypergeometric function to see what they're all about ! :D

Comment: @IraGessel - So do you know what it means to have those "-" symbols in there? It's not mentioned on the Wikipedia page, and the best guess I could come up with for it would be equivalent to having a "1" in that position, which seems much clearer.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC When there are no numerator parameters or no denominators (i.e., $_pF_0$ or $_0F_q$) it's customary to put in a dash instead of nothing in the place of these nonexistent parameters. So, for example,
$$_0F_1\left[{-\atop \tfrac12};\frac{x^2}{4}\right]$$
is the same as 
$$_0F_1\left[{\atop \tfrac12};\frac{x^2}{4}\right].$$

Comment: Thank you all for a swift and accurate answer to my doubts !! :D

Answer (score 1):

These notations are as @JonathanZ supports MonicaC and @IraGessel points out in the comments are for *Generalized Hypergeometric Functions* that special-cases into more famous functions like $e^x$, $\sinh (x)$, $\cos(x)$ etc. These hypergeometric functions are more generalized versions of regular geometric series $ \sum_{k=0}^n ar^k$.

Comment: A good source for properties of generalised hypergeometric functions is the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16).

Comment: Oh wow ! Thanks @Gary ! Will explore them